# How does Radix Sort work?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, radix-sort

I don't know why this is so hard for me to wrap my head around.  I've looked through the wiki pages, and pseudo code (as well as actual code) trying to understand how radix sort algorithms work (with respect to buckets).

Am I looking into the wrong thing here?  Should I be looking into bucket sort maybe?  Can someone give me a dumbed down version of how it works?  For reference, here is a codeblock that *supposedly* performs a radix sort:

```
// Sort 'size' number of integers starting at 'input' according to the 'digit'th digit
// For the parameter 'digit', 0 denotes the least significant digit and increases as significance does
void radixSort(int* input, int size, int digit)
{
    if (size == 0)
        return;

    int[10] buckets;    // assuming decimal numbers

    // Sort the array in place while keeping track of bucket starting indices.
    // If bucket[i] is meant to be empty (no numbers with i at the specified digit),
    // then let bucket[i+1] = bucket[i]

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        radixSort(input + buckets[i], buckets[i+1] - buckets[i], digit+1);
    }
}
```

And I've looked at non-recursive solutions also:

```
void radixsort(int *a, int arraySize)
{
    int i, bucket[sortsize], maxVal = 0, digitPosition =1 ;
    for(i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        if(a[i] > maxVal) maxVal = a[i];
    }

    int pass = 1; 
    while(maxVal/digitPosition > 0) {
        // reset counter 
        int digitCount[10] = {0};

        // count pos-th digits (keys) 
        for(i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
            digitCount[a[i]/digitPosition%10]++;

        // accumulated count 
        for(i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            digitCount[i] += digitCount[i-1];

        // To keep the order, start from back side
        for(i = arraySize - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            bucket[--digitCount[a[i]/digitPosition%10]] = a[i];

        for(i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
            a[i] = bucket[i];

        cout << "pass #" << pass++ << ": ";
        digitPosition *= 10;
    } 

}
```

Specifically, this line is giving me troubles.  I've tried walking through it with pen and paper, but I still can't figure out what this is doing:

```
   // To keep the order, start from back side
        for(i = arraySize - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            bucket[--digitCount[a[i]/digitPosition%10]] = a[i];
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Examples has a great example inside.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

In mathematics, radix means base, where decimal would be base 10. Imagine you have numbers some of which having more than one digits like

```
5, 213, 55, 21, 2334, 31, 20, 430
```

For simplicity, say you want to use the decimal radix (=10) for sorting. Then you would start by separating the numbers by units and then putting them together again; next you would separate the numbers by tens and then put them together again; then by hundreds and so on until all the numbers are sorted. Each time you loop, just read the list from left to right. You can also imagine you are separating the numbers into buckets. Here is an illustration using `5, 213, 55, 21, 2334, 31, 20, 430`

Separate by units:

- zeros: 20, 430
- ones: 21, 31
- twos:
- threes: 213
- fours: 2334
- fives: 5, 55

  Back together: 20, 430, 21, 31, 213, 2334, 5, 55

To put them back together, first read the `zeroes` bucket, then the `ones` bucket, then so on, until you read the `nines` bucket.

Separate by tens:

- zeros: 05
- ones: 213
- twos: 20, 21
- threes: 430, 31, 2334,
- fours:
- fives: 55

  Back together: 5, 213, 20, 21, 430, 31, 2334, 55

Separate by hundreds:

- zeros: 005, 020, 021, 031, 055
- ones:
- twos: 213
- threes: 2334
- fours: 430
- fives:

  Back together: 5, 20, 21, 31, 55, 213, 2334, 430

Separate by thousands:

- zeros: 0005, 0020, 0021, 0031, 0055, 0213, 0430
- ones:
- twos: 2334
- threes:
- fours:
- fives:

  Back together: 5, 20, 21, 31, 55, 213, 430, 2334

You are now done. I saw a nice code for this on Geekviewpoint both in [Java](http://www.geekviewpoint.com/java/sorting/radixsort) and in [python](http://www.geekviewpoint.com/python/sorting/radixsort)

Comment: Wow! That's a lot of details. You really went for it there. Great job. +1

Comment: @kasavbere I have great appreciation for `stackoverflow` and a lot of respect for people who ask for help.

Comment: Could you also explain how would it change the radix sorting if we would need to use different base? For ex. our max number would be 1 000 000^2, so if I am guessing right, we could use base 256. But how would it change the algorithm?

Comment: i just love it when someone explains in absolute layman breaking things down to cellular level!! :D

Answer (score 3):

This is the basic flow of quicksort.

**For 1st pass:** we sort the array on basis of least significant digit (1s place) using counting sort. Notice that 435 is below 835, because 435 occurred below 835 in the original list.

**For 2nd pass:** we sort the array on basis of next digit (10s place) using counting sort. Notice that here 608 is below 704, because 608 occurred below 704 in the previous list, and similarly for (835, 435) and (751, 453).

**For 3rd pass:** we sort the array on basis of most significant digit (100s place) using counting sort. Notice that here 435 is below 453, because 435 occurred below 453 in the previous list, and similarly for (608, 690) and (704, 751).

[image]

For more details [you can refer to this blog on codingeek and have clear understanding](http://www.codingeek.com/algorithms/radix-sort-explanation-pseudocode-and-implementation/).

Answer (score 2):

Think of a deck of cards. You first sort it by suit in four piles. Then you put those four piles on top of one another and now sort into 13 piles based on rank. Put those together and you now have a sorted deck.

Comment: "sort .. based on rank" is a *poor analogy* for a radix sort as it implies comparison while ordering. e.g.: when I sort a suite of cards by hand, I put a 4 before the 9, then a 5 after the 4 but before the 9 and a 3 before the 4, etc ..

Comment: @pst: Please elaborate - how does it imply ordering?

Comment: It implies *comparison* while ordering. Analogies model real life - and in this case, as per the operation I described, the analogy diverges from what it is trying to describe. The first part, about the four piles *is* what a Radix sort is about, only with one restriction: the piles are always ranged in a specific order. (And this order is because someone said it was so, and *not because of any comparison* between the decks.)

Comment: I guess it can be read both ways (and I'm not entirely sure of my reading): +1, but it would be nice to see this answer flushed out more.

Comment: i don't know.  i think it works better if it were something like... you've got 13 slots/buckets for rank, you put cards into their respective slot and then take them back out from the lowest slot to the highest slot.  viola.  they're sorted.  you didn't have to do any comparison.

Answer (score 0):

may be my code could help you:)

Here is python`s code of Radix Sort:

```
import random,time

from random import randint

A=[random.randint(1,1212) for i in range(23)]


length = len(str(max(A)))

print(length) 

rang = 10

print(A)

start=time.time()

for i in range(length):

B = [[] for k in range(rang)]

for x in A:

    figure =x // (10**i) % 10

    B[figure].append(x)

A = []

for k in range(rang):

    A+=B[k]

end=time.time()

print(end-start)

print(A)
```