# Sort rectangles according to area in O(N)

Tags: algorithm

Let R1,...Rn be n axis-aligned rectangles in the plane for which the corners are points in the n×n-grid. Thus, for each rectangle Ri the four corners are points where both coordinates are integers in {1,...n}.

Now I want to sort these rectangles R1,...Rn by there increasing area in O(n) time.

I have an algorithm to sort them in O(n*log n). But how can it be done in O(n) ?

Using O(n*log n) we can do this :

```
Calculate all the areas, and then sort using any standard sorting algorithm like Quick sort
```

I guess some per-processing will be required, so that we can sort in O(n) , because we are given some pre-conditions which can help. I just want algorithm, no code required.

Comment: As the resulting areas are integer numbers, you can implement a [radix sort](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14717560/4856258) algorithm.

Comment: @TagirValeev How radix sort is going to help here?

Comment: @python_slayer A radix sort is a [*non-comparison sort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Radix_sort) and runs in "O(n)" when k << n (see link for details). The O(n lg n) lower bounds are for a *comparison* sort.

Comment: @TagirValeev Whats better ? Counting sort or radix sort in this case

Comment: @python_slayer, I guess that counting sort is inappropriate in your case.

Comment: @TagirValeev Reason ? Why inappropriate ? In answer below one comment is "You would use radix sort if you had representations of the integers in e.g., base 10 or base 2 notation. But you don't have representations of the integers, you have the integers themselves, so use counting sort. (Actually the answer depends on the size of n ... if it's bigger than maximum long integer you'd essentially have to use a radix sort, but that's highly unlikely). "

Answer (score 1):

Since the keys (areas) of the rectangles are integers, the task can be completed in `O(n)` time using a [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort#The_algorithm). You know the minimum key is 0 and maximum key for the problem is `n^2`, so in the algorithm `k=n^2+1`. The algorithm completes in three passes: computing histogram, computing starting and ending indexes for each key, then copying the data to the output array, preserving order of inputs with equal keys so that the sort is [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability). Each pass is `O(n)` so altogether the algorithm is `O(n)`.

Example: Suppose n is 3. k is one more than the largest key that appears in the data, so that all keys fit in the range [0..k-1] inclusive, i.e., k is 10. You make a histogram h by setting up an array of 0s with index from 0 to k-1, and you fill the histogram by walking through your set of rectangles and just count them up. Say there are 2 with area 1, 5 with area 2, and 2 with area 4. h = [0, 2, 5, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]. Then the starting indexes are immediately computed from the histogram as 0, 0, 2, 7, 7, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9. Any rectangle with area 0 goes into output array starting at 0. Any rectangle with area 1 goes into output array starting at 0 (and increment that number when you put a rectangle of area 1 into output). Any rectangle with area 2 goes into output array starting at 2. Any rectangle with area 3 goes into output array starting at 7. Any rectangle with area 4 goes into output array starting at 7.

Comment: Can you explain by some example ? Whats K here ?

Comment: What will be better radix sort or counting sort ?

Comment: I gave an example. You would use radix sort if you had representations of the integers in e.g., base 10 or base 2 notation. But you don't have representations of the integers, you have the integers themselves, so use counting sort. (Actually the answer depends on the size of n ... if it's bigger than maximum long integer you'd essentially have to use a radix sort, but that's highly unlikely).

Comment: I just noticed my example has wrong number of rectangles (should be n, as per OP). I'll correct shortly.

Comment: I don't get why it's in O(n). Doesn't the wikipedia page say it's in O(k+n)? So if k = n^2 + 1, doesn't that mean the algorithm is in O(n^2 + n) = O(n^2)?

Comment: Dammit @user3472 you're right.  My array has O(n^2) elements.  I don't know what I was thinking.  Will think about this some more, but maybe a radix sort is the way to go?